# Disable extend session pop-up for all window if user is active

Tags: jquery

In My screens.js  i check user is idle or not.If it is idle then i will show seeion extend popup.But Problem is that is used above screen.js is reference to all pages.(Which is common .js)

```
$('*').bind('mousemove click mouseup mousedown keydown keypress keyup submit change mouseenter scroll resize dblclick', function () {
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    console.log("idleState" + idleState);
    idleState = false;
    idleTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        //console.log("idleTimer:" + idleState);
        idleState = true;
        console.log("idleState" + idleState);
    }, 5000);//60000
});
$("body").trigger("mousemove");

sessionCheckInterval = setInterval(showSessionExpireModal, 5000);//60000
```

Above one for checking user is idle.

After that i set interval which check user idle state and session time. If user is idle and session time is equal to session expire then session extend pop up show.

Let take scenario.
if user open up X page and Y page on X page user perform some activity means user in not idle. But On Y page user won't perform any activity means user is idle. Because of  that Y page Session Extend pop will show up which i don't want because user is performing activity on X Page.

```
  sessionCheckInterval = setInterval(showSessionExpireModal, 5000);//interval for session pop up
```

function code is here....

```
function showSessionExpireModal() {
    currentSystemTime = new Date(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
    if (!idleState) return;
    console.log("idleState:" + idleState + " currentSystemTime: " + currentSystemTime + " sessionExpiredTime: " + sessionExpiredTime);
    if ((idleState) && moment(currentSystemTime).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss') == moment(sessionExpiredTime).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')) {
            $('#SessionExpireModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
            currentSystemTime = new Date(moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
            sessionExpiredTime = new Date(moment(moment(new Date(currentSystemTime)).add(1, 'm').toDate()).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
            countDownInterval = setInterval(function () {
                counter = counter - duration;
                if (counter == 0) {
                    $('#SessionExpireModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                    clearTimeout(countDownInterval);
                    counter = 60;
                    clearTimeout(sessionCheckInterval);
                    window.location.href =  '/User/SessionExpired';
                }
                $('#countDownTimer').text(counter);
            }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Is that possible to prevent modal pop up if user perform activity on one screen compare to others. Any Suggestion

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you could not solve this problem with JavaScript.

You should control the Users activity with a server session handling. E.g. send a "I'm a live signal" via AJAX on any action to the server. Save the last activity time in a session variable and ask via AJAX in an interval the last activity time respectively the time difference between now and last activity. Depending on the difference you can show a PopUp (on every open page).

A little bit more complex would by a solution with session depending WebSockets.